# How can I stop many MovieClips with for Loop

Tags: actionscript-3, parent-child, movieclip

I use this code:

```
parantClip.childClip1.stop();
parantClip.childClip2.stop();
parantClip.childClip3.stop();
parantClip.childClip4.stop();
parantClip.childClip5.stop();
parantClip.childClip6.stop();
parantClip.childClip7.stop();
parantClip.childClip8.stop();
```

But I want to do this:

```
for(var k:int=1; k<9; k++)
    MovieClip(root).parentClip.["childClip"+k].stop();
```

How can i do this?

Comment: `.parentClip["childClip"+k]`, without a dot before bracket.

Comment: i was using extra dot. So code dont work. Thank you for your information

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(parantClip["childClip" + k] as MovieClip).stop();
```